# How to correctly set the database, table, and column collation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql-8.0, collation

## Background

I am experiencing problems setting the collation in my local MySQL database I am using for a Drupal site I am developing. I attempted to create a local database with charset `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as recommended by Drupal docs, but MySQL still sets connection collation and server collation was `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` which results in some tables and columns using this incorrect collation.

When it came time to import the database into my staging server, I experienced the error `ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'`. Upon closer investigation, it appeared that some tables and columns were using the `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. I am confused how this happened because I thought that the tables and columns would use the database collation I set, not the server/connection collation.

This ballooned into a much larger issue because I could not import the database backups into the staging server without altering the database, tables, and columns to change the collation. After I changed each table and column to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` the import worked, but the site started throwing `EntityStorageException` and `IntegrityConstraintViolationException` errors, so I am worried I may have corrupted the data somehow when I altered the collation.

## Setup

I used MySQLWorkbench to connect to my root cluster and created a new database. In the Schema editor, I selected the following options:

[image]

Following this, I ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';` to check the collation which reveals that only the database collation has what I selected.

[image]

I expected that the table and column collation would be the same as my database collation, but unexpectedly many of my tables and columns ended up using `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` which resulted in the error mentioned above.

## Export & Import

I used MySQLWorkbench for this.

### Export

1. `Server` > `Data Export`
2. Checkmarked cabTest, selected "Export to Self-Contained File" (no other settings checked/selected)
3. Started export

### Import

1. `Server` > `Data Import`
2. Selected "Import from Self-Contained File" and the empty database I was importing into.
3. Started import

This fails and results in `Error 1273` mentioned above.

## Question

Just to be clear, I am not looking for how to fix this issue or recover my lost data, but how to set my database up so that the database, tables and columns all use the collation which I selected when I created the database. I want to be able to export and import the MySQL dump more easily without having to carry out any alter statements. How do I create the database correctly so that it uses `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for the database, as well as the tables and columns?

## Additional Info

- The staging server uses `5.7.42-log`, while my local database is 8.0.34
- I do not have any control over the staging server version or collation